# Polymer1.0: Single/multiple IronAjax?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am wondering if it wise to use single IronAjax for whole app? Otherwise I run into a situation where almost every view require an IronAjax. I mean its not hurting me creating multiple ironajax, but naming them, and naming success and error messages need to be unique. otherwise they can conflict on any other ironajax method which is defined within the tree. I ran into this situation before.

So I am not looking for "what is possible", I am looking for best practices.

Comment: Using a single iron-ajax element would probably be more efficient.

Comment: Can you expand upon the structure of your app? If you're encapsulating ajax requests in your elements (including error handling), there shouldn't be any concerns associated with naming or multiple calls. I'm not sure how you would even use one iron-ajax request for the whole app.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal: Can you give any example about how to get hold of an ironajax which is defined on a parent component? Specially, isn't that "onSuccess" and "onError" methods will be triggered for all implementations on child? Please give an example.

Comment: @anthony: I am not sure how to use single ironajax in whole app

Answer (score 0):

A single Iron Ajax would indeed be more efficient, as long as the code in the error and response handlers do not need to be too different based on the URL retrieved. This question is mainly a philosophical argument and does not have a definitive answer since both ways possible and the direction depends on your comfort level of supporting the application.